# CSS. Как при наведении курсора на один элемент списка, текущий элемент окрашивался в зеленый, а элемент через него в красный?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой кусок кода

```
<div>
   <ol>
            <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
            <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
            <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
        
   </ol>
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 6):

```css
.block:hover {
  background: green;
}

.block:hover+li+li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
  <li class="block">Пункт li</li>
</ol>
```